# Floating Div in IE7

Tags: html, css

I really hoped my IE7 woes were over, but my company still supports it across our enterprise, so alas I'm stuck with fixing some glitches. I must be overlooking something incredibly silly, and I was wondering if a fresh set of eyes can help fix. So in this problem, my text div that I have is suppose to float along side the image div, but it isn't working.

```
<div id="news-container">
    <div class="news-item">
        <div class="news-image" style="background:url('images/site/previewimage.png') no-repeat;">
            <img src="images/site/image-border.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="news-text">
            <h1>Latest News</h1>
            <h2><a href="#">"Almost, Maine" Tickets are now on sale!</a></h2>
            <p>Text blah blah blah.</p>
            <div class="linkbutton redlink"><a href="#">Read More</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS...

```
#news-container {
    width:100%;
    margin:20px 0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}
.news-item {
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.news-image {
    height:210px;
    width:340px;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.news-text {
    width:900px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: does this work in other browsers, as reading the code, I wouldn't have thought it would work at all, in any browser

Comment: Yes, it's worked when testing in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It just seems like a strange thing to try and do, put two items with widths of 340px and 900px (.news-image and .news-text respectively) inside an element of 960px (.news-item). I personally don't see the need for the width on the .news-text, I would let it just fill the rest of the .news-item box

Comment: I didn't even notice that: it was supposed to be 600px and I never even noticed that. This is why fresh eyes is a huge help: thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *really* working in Chrome and Firefox.

What's happening is, when you float an element, text within elements that surround the float (that are still in the document flow) will move aside for that float, however the container itself (in your case, `.news-text` still starts in the same left position.

If your text goes longer than the image, you will see the text fall to the same left starting position as your image.

To get a proper "hanging indent", you need to assign a width to `.news-text` that is the remainder of the width leftover by the image, and set a left margin to push it away from the image. This will work in all browsers including IE 7.

Preview in IE 7: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EqWA4/show/

To see the code: http://jsfiddle.net/EqWA4/

```
.news-text {
    width:500px;
    margin-left: 365px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```